# Изменить фон button при фокусе input

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка и css

```css
#headerSearchDiv form input[type="text"]:focus #headerSearchDiv form button {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerSearchDiv">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Поиск">
                        <button>Найти</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Но почему-то при фокусе input ничего не меняется у button...

Пробовал и `#headerSearchDiv form input[type="text"]:focus + #headerSearchDiv form button {` и `#headerSearchDiv form input[type="text"]:focus ~ #headerSearchDiv form button {`

не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type="text"]:focus ~ button {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerSearchDiv">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Поиск">
    <button>Найти</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, в данном случае лучше использовать + а не ~. Так как если кнопок будет несколько- красными станут все, а не одна (как в случае с +)